# Testing spring bean with post construct

Tags: spring, junit, postconstruct

I have a bean similar to this:

```
@Service
public class A {

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
       b.call(param);
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { Application.class, Config.class })
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    B b;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        when(b.call(any())).thenReturn("smth");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        // test...
    }
}
```

The problem is that `PostConstruct` is called before `setUp` when the test is run.

Comment: @hzpz Class A have other logic which is called in test latter. And answering your question I would like to test logic of the class A.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to write a **unit** test of `A`, then don't use Spring. Instead, instantiate `A` yourself and pass a stub/mock of `B` (either by using constructor injection or `ReflectionTestUtils` to set the private field).

For example:

```
@Service
public class A {

    private final B b;    

    @Autowired
    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
       b.call(param);
    }
}
```

-

```
public class Test {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        B b = mock(b);
        A a = new A(b);
        // write some tests for A
    }

}
```

If you have to use Spring, because you want to write an **integration** test, use a different application context, where you replace `B` with a stub/mock.

For example, assuming `B` is instantiated in a `Production` class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Production {

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B();
    }

}
```

Write another `@Configuration` class for your tests:

```
@Configuration
public class Tests {

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        // using Mockito is just an example
        B b = Mockito.mock(B.class); 
        Mockito.when(b).thenReturn("smth"); 
        return b;
    }

}
```

Reference it in your test with the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` annotation:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { Application.class, Tests.class })
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is almost right. Additionally
`@Configuration
public class Tests {

    @Bean
    public B b() {
     B b = Mockito.mock(B.class);
     Mockito.when(b).thenReturn("smth");
        return b;
    }

}`

Comment: this 1st part of the solution is avoiding the real problem by killing the “integration” part of the test. The 2nd part is much better

Comment: @cahen That is why I started with "If you want to write a **unit** test". In my experience, people often tend to write integration test when they actually want a unit test.

Comment: @Andy I updated my answer according to your comment.

Comment: In first part of solution you avoiding a problem, in second part of solution you also avoiding the problem by not using @Service annotation

Comment: This is _one_ valid solution that fits the question. There may be others. If you have a different problem for which this is not a solution, please ask a new question instead of downvoting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this exact problem on a project I'm working on, Here is the solution I used in terms of the question code:

1. `@Autowire` in the bean with the `@PostConstruct` to your test.
2. Do your setup in the `@Before`.
3. Explicitly call the `@PostConstruct` at the end of your `@Before`.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { Application.class, Config.class })
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
public class Test {

    // wire in the dependency as well
    @Autowired
    A a;

    @Autowired
    B b;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        when(b.call(any())).thenReturn("smth");
        
        // "manual" call to @PostConstruct which will now work as expected
        a.setup(); 
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        // test...
    }
}
```

Obviously your `@PostConstruct` method has to be idempotent as its going to get called twice. Also it assumes default singleton bean behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

another alternative is to instantiate the application context on the test yourself and then inject the mocks prior to refreshing the context, for example, as in:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class TestConfiguration {}
...
ClassToMock mock = mock(ClassToMock.class);
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext c = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
c.getDefaultListableBeanFactory().registerResolvableDependency(
        ClassToMock.class,
        mock);
c.register(TestConfiguration.class);
c.refresh();
```

This alternative is useful when there are `@PostConstruct` annotations on the context and you want to set expectations on the mock prior.