# Configure @MockBean component before application start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mocking, integration-testing

I have a Spring Boot 1.4.2 application. Some code that is used during startup looks like this:

```
@Component 
class SystemTypeDetector{
    public enum SystemType{ TYPE_A, TYPE_B, TYPE_C }
    public SystemType getSystemType(){ return ... }
}

@Component 
public class SomeOtherComponent{
    @Autowired 
    private SystemTypeDetector systemTypeDetector;
    @PostConstruct 
    public void startup(){
        switch(systemTypeDetector.getSystemType()){   // <-- NPE here in test
        case TYPE_A: ...
        case TYPE_B: ...
        case TYPE_C: ...
        }
    }
}
```

There is a component that determines the system type. This component is used during startup from other components. In production, everything works fine.

Now I want to add some integration tests using Spring 1.4's `@MockBean`.

The test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyWebApplication.class, webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTestNrOne {
    @MockBean 
    private SystemTypeDetector systemTypeDetectorMock;

    @Before 
    public void initMock(){
       Mockito.when(systemTypeDetectorMock.getSystemType()).thenReturn(TYPE_C);
    }

    @Test 
    public void testNrOne(){
      // ...
    }
}
```

Basically, the mocking works fine. My systemTypeDetectorMock is used and if I call `getSystemType` -> `TYPE_C` is returned.

**The problem** is that the application doesn't start. Currently springs working order seems to be:

1. create all Mocks (without configuration all methods return null)
2. start the application
3. call `@Before`-methods (where the mocks would be configured)
4. start test

My problem is that the application starts with an uninitialized mock. So the call to `getSystemType()` returns null.

My question is: How can I configure the mocks *before* application startup?

**EDIT:**
If somebody has the same problem, one *workaround* is to use `@MockBean(answer = CALLS_REAL_METHODS)`. This calls the real component and in my case, the system starts up. After startup, I can change the mock behavior.

Comment: You can inject mock and call initialization code by hand as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31587946/3440376

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Using `Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS` I was able provide a fake implementation in a subclass taking effect before the set up of other beans, and avoid use of `@Primary`.

Comment: I've added your edit as a standalone answer, as that's basically what it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77531830/1108305

Answer (score 61):

In this case you need to configure mocks in a way we used to do it before `@MockBean` was introduced - by specifying manually a `@Primary` bean that will replace the original one in the context.

```java
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public SystemTypeDetector mockSystemTypeDetector() {
            SystemTypeDetector std = mock(SystemTypeDetector.class);
            when(std.getSystemType()).thenReturn(TYPE_C);
            return std;
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    private SystemTypeDetector systemTypeDetector;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertThat(systemTypeDetector.getSystemType()).isEqualTo(TYPE_C);
    }
}
```

Since `@TestConfiguration` class is a static inner class it will be picked automatically only by this test. Complete mock behaviour that you would put into `@Before` has to be moved to method that initialises a bean.

Comment: it worked after setting `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`

Comment: this is working in Spring Boot 2.0.9... as it is in the original answer

Comment: this works, but how to change the stub for every test case ?

Comment: Move `when` out from the `@Bean` annotated method, and call `reset` on this bean in `@BeforeEach` method.

Comment: If you, like me, write a test with a limited Spring context, ie. `@SpringBootTest(classes = {...})`, you have to add `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DemoApplicationTests.TestConfig.class})` to your test class as well for the bean to be autowirable.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to fix it like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyWebApplication.class, webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTestNrOne {
    // this inner class must be static!
    @TestConfiguration
    public static class EarlyConfiguration {
       @MockBean 
       private SystemTypeDetector systemTypeDetectorMock;

       @PostConstruct 
       public void initMock(){
          Mockito.when(systemTypeDetectorMock.getSystemType()).thenReturn(TYPE_C);
       }
    }

    // here we can inject the bean created by EarlyConfiguration
    @Autowired 
    private SystemTypeDetector systemTypeDetectorMock;

    @Autowired
    private SomeOtherComponent someOtherComponent;

    @Test 
    public void testNrOne(){
       someOtherComponent.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: I used solution for creating mock from Maciej Walkowiak and this injection worked for me in Spring Boot 2.0.9 -> use Autowired on mocked instance instead MockBean

Comment: Super vote up this answer! You saved my day!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following trick:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public BeanA beanA() {
        return new BeanA();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanB beanB() {
        return new BeanB(beanA());
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class, Config.class})
public class ConfigTest {

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {

        @MockBean
        BeanA beanA;

        @PostConstruct
        void setUp() {
            when(beanA.someMethod()).thenReturn(...);
        }
    }
}
```

At least it's working for `spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case (as you mentioned in an edit to your answer), as a workaround you can use `@MockBean(answer = CALLS_REAL_METHODS)`.  This will use the actual method implementation at startup.  Then within tests that need to mock out the value, you can specify mocks as normal.

Answer (score -1):

Spring's initialization is triggered before `@Before` Mockito's annotation so the mock is not initialized at the time the `@PostConstruct` annotated method is executed.

Try to 'delay' your system detection using `@Lazy` annotation on the `SystemTypeDetector` component. Use your `SystemTypeDetector` where you need it, keep in mind that you cannot trigger this detection in a `@PostConstruct` or equivalent hook.

Answer (score -2):

I think that it's due to the way you autowire your dependencies. Take a look at [this](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/) (specially the part about 'Fix #1: Solve your design and make your dependencies visible'). That way you can also avoid using the `@PostConstruct` and just use the constructor instead.

Answer (score -4):

What U are using, is good for a unit tests:

```
org.mockito.Mockito#when()
```

Try to use the following methods for mocking spring beans when the context is spined-up:

```
org.mockito.BDDMockito#given()
```

If u are using @SpyBean, then u should use another syntax:

```
willReturn(Arrays.asList(val1, val2))
        .given(service).getEntities(any());
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question. The question is about MockBean for spring-boot tests, not simple mocking in a regular JUnit test.