# How to create a @MockBean with pre-defined answers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I have a MockBean in my test:

```
@MockBean(SomeClient.class)
SomeClient client;
```

I'm starting up a spring-boot test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop" })
```

On spring startup, one of my services is trying to call a method that returns an object, then gets the ID from the returned object:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    public SomeService(final SomeClient someClient) {
        this.someClient = someClient;

        this.clientId = someClient.clientMetadata().getId(); << NullPointerException Here
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting a NullPointerException because .clientMetadata() returns null.

How do I go about setting up the mock bean so that it returns a Metadata object with the ID populated on it?

Using:

- Java 8
- JUnit 5
- spring-boot-starter-test 2.2.9.RELEASE

PS - I can't use `@BeforeEach` because it tries to boot the app *before* it executes the beforeEach method.

Comment: seems like something extremely similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563409/configure-mockbean-component-before-application-start