# Configuring a Mock as the application context loads

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

We are using Spring-boot 2.3.5.  One of our classes uses a @PostConstruct annotation and this is causing me a lot of problems in testing.  It seems to me that the order of events is

1. create all Mocks
2. start application
3. call @Before-methods
4. start test

(As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563409/configure-mockbean-component-before-application-start) to largely the same question )

My issue is that I have a lot of beans mocked but the the @PostConstruct method is called before the mocks are configured in any @Before methods.

So I have

```
Service {
 
@AutoWired  
componentOne
 
@AutoWired  
componentTwo
 
@AutoWired  
componentThree
 
…
 
@PostConstruct
public void doSomeWork() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    …
}
```

And Test Class

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.yml")
@ActiveProfiles("development")
public abstract class AbstractTests {
 
 
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
 
    @Value("${server.servlet.context-path}")
    String contextPath;
 
    protected final Faker faker = new Faker(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-GB"));
 
    @Autowired
    protected SettingsService settingsService;
 
    @MockBean
    private ServiceOne accountingImportService;
 
    @MockBean
    private ServiceTwo accountingImportService;
 
    @MockBean
    private ServiceThree accountingImportService;
 
@BeforeEach
public void setup() throws Exception {
 
… configure mocks
```

The @PostConstruct fires before the mocks are configured and fails.

I have tried (from the linked question)

```
@MockBean(answer = CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
protected SsoService ssoService;
```

Which doesn’t seem to help at all

and

```
@TestConfiguration
public static class EarlyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Service mockService() {
        Service service = mock(Service.class);
        when(service.getLocalTimeZone()).thenReturn(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        return service;
    }
}

@Autowired
protected Service service;
```

And this fails on the auto wire because it can’t configure the class with its autowired (mocked) dependencies.

Is there a simple way to configure a when in a static context as the mockBean is declared ?